# importing a class in the typescript

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript

when importing a class from another module then the compiler gives this error,tell me how to correct it

```
(function  (exports,  require,  module, __filename,  __dirname) {  import validator from './click.component';
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError:  Unexpected  identifier

    at  new  Script  (vm.js:74:7)


    at  createScript  (vm.js:246:10)


    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile 

(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js

(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)

    at Module.load 

(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)

    at tryModuleLoad 

(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)

    at Function.Module._load

 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain
```

> Blockquote how can i fix this

(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
        at startup

(internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)

Answer (score 1):

> SyntaxError:  Unexpected  identifier

Means you are trying to run an `import` statement in a runtime that doesn't support it.

## Fix

Make sure you have compiled your TypeScript to JavaScript with `--module commonjs`